# Using integer to retrieve value from list

Tags: python

I'm writing my first program ever in Python, and I want to use an input, convert it to an integer, and then use that integer to call a value from a list. This is the code that I have so far.

```
number = raw_input("How many paychecks have you received?") #asking question

number = int(number) #converting answer to integer


ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n/10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4]) #ordinal list i got from stackoverflow lol (credit to Gareth on CodeGolf)


a = [ordinal(n) for n in range(1,1000)]
```

How would I use "number" to call a value from the ordinal list? What I mean is if the user inputs "1" how would I use that to return the string "First", "2" for "Second", "3" for "Third", etc.

Comment: You can simply `print ordinal(number)`, but keep in mind this will print `1st` not `First`.

Comment: You're already using ordinal on the line that assigns `a`

Comment: Why would you copy paste complex code into your first ever python program?

Answer (score 0):

`print a[number - 1]` if you want to use the precomputed list or `print ordinal(number)` directly using the function.

Keep in mind though, that `a` has the following content according to your code:

```
['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', ... ]
```